# Show D (differentiable functions) is a subring of R

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let R be a ring of functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and let $D
\subset R$ be the set of differentiable functions. Show D is a subring of R.

I know I have to show D is a group under addition (D,+) and that it is closed under multiplication and $1 \in D$ but I'm not sure how to get there. I think the differentiation is stumping me. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: That it is indeed what you need to show. Which of these properties do you get stuck at?

Comment: How about the identity under addition. Is this just a continuous polynomial that equals zero?

Comment: It is the constant zero functions, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yep, think I'm answering my own questions here:)